# update value in google sheet with if condition in another column using python

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a similar data as below in google sheet.
I want to update the pageId for pagename "abc".

[image: PageName page id xyz 24324354_a abc 12345678_b lmn 98765432_c]

I'm able to update manually passing B3 `sheet.update('B3','updated_value')`
but How should I get B3 by adding a if condition where pagename=abc in python code.

Need help.

Comment: ```records_data = sheet_instance.get_all_records()
test = sheet_instance.col_values(1)
rownum = test.index('abc') + 1
print(rownum)
row = sheet_instance.row_values(rownum)
print(row)```

I'm able to get the row number but I need cell number like B3 to be passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your provided script in your comment is used, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
# Your provided script in your comment.
records_data = sheet_instance.get_all_records()
test = sheet_instance.col_values(1)
rownum = test.index('abc') + 1
print(rownum)
row = sheet_instance.row_values(rownum)
print(row)

sheet_instance.update_cell(rownum, 2, 'Updated') # Added
```

- In this case, `rownum` can be directly used.

#### Reference:

- [Updating Cells](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.1.1/user-guide.html#updating-cells)